# How to make a selector a valid selector

Tags: jquery, selector

In my code I am told about a selector not being a valid one. After hours of googling and not finding anything valid I am turning here. What am I doing wrong? The mycell is said not being valid. The Here comes the code in question...

```
function correct(tier, reihe, spalte) {
  console.log("Falsch!");
  switch (tier) {
    case 1:
    case 6:
    case 8:
      console.log("Tier: " + tier);
      // var mytarget = document.getElementsByClassName("target");
      var count = ((reihe - 1) * 3) + spalte;
      console.log ("Count: " + count);
      var mycell = document.querySelectorAll(".target table:nth-child(count)");
      console.log (mycell);
      for (i=0; i < 9; i++)
      if (spalte == 0) {

      }
      break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 7:
      if (spalte == 1) {
        console.log("Stimmt!");
        empty[((reihe - 1) + spalte)] = false;
        console.log(empty[((reihe - 1) + spalte)]);
      } else {
        correct(tier, reihe, spalte);
      }
      break;

    case 2:
    case 5:
    case 9:
      if (spalte == 2) {
        console.log("Stimmt!");
        empty[((reihe - 1) + spalte)] = false;
        console.log(empty[((reihe - 1) + spalte)]);
      } else {
        correct(tier, reihe, spalte);
      }
      break;

  }

}
```

Comment: `\`.target table:nth-child(${count})\``

Comment: I am sorry dear @glinda93, this selector is invalid as well.